# Does Intel WiDi (wireless display technology) lock the wireless adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, display

If I setup an Intel WiDi system, will it use/lock my WiFi connection, so that I'm unable to connect to a router for internet access?

Answer (score 0):

If I've researched correctly it seems that Intel WiDi doesn't block the wireless adapter, so I can still connect to a WiFi spot while displaying wirelessly to my TV!